# Angular Material bottomsheet, trouble trying to pass a variable as data

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material, angular8

Trying to pass a variable as data to a bottomsheet in Angular 8 Material. 
Following their documentation, I am able to successfully pass a string to the bottomsheet, but am not able to pass a variable through. Could anyone help? I appreciate any and all advice.

Here is the TS and HTML of the bottom sheet I want to open up

```
//HTML Portion

<div> passed in {{data.searchResults}}</div>

// TS Portion

import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { MatBottomSheetRef, MAT_BOTTOM_SHEET_DATA } from '@angular/material/bottom-sheet';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-singlejobpage',
  templateUrl: './singlejobpage.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./singlejobpage.component.scss']
})
export class SinglejobpageComponent {

  constructor(@Inject(MAT_BOTTOM_SHEET_DATA) public data: any, private _bottomSheetRef: MatBottomSheetRef<SinglejobpageComponent>) { }

  openLink(event: MouseEvent): void {
    this._bottomSheetRef.dismiss();
    event.preventDefault();
  }


}
```

Below Here is my mainpage.TS where I am trying to send the data.

```
 openBottomSheet(): void {
    this._bottomSheet.open(SinglejobpageComponent, {
      data: { searchResults: this.filteredData }
    });
  }

  filterForone(y) {
    let filteredData = this.jobs.filter(x => x.data.title === y)
    console.log(filteredData)
    console.log(filteredData[0].data.title)
    this.openBottomSheet();
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are referencing `this.data` but in your code you never set this property.

try:

```
 openBottomSheet(): void {
    this._bottomSheet.open(SinglejobpageComponent, {
      data: { searchResults: this.filteredData }
    });
  }

  filterForone(y) {
    this.filteredData = this.jobs.filter(x => x.data.title === y)
    console.log(this.filteredData)
    console.log(this.filteredData[0].data.title)
    this.openBottomSheet();
  }
```

Comment: Hey I see what you mean, I was not setting the variable outside of that function! You solved my problem, thanks a bunch!